# The body of a for-in should be wrapped in an if statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype eslint

Tags: javascript, browser, eslint, ecmascript-5

I know this has been asked before, but I don't quite understand why am I still getting this error after I already have the solution in every post an every answer.

I have the following code:

```js
        for (key in datosMostrados) {
            if (datosMostrados.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                // my logic goes here
            }
        }
```

I still get the error `The body of a for-in should be wrapped in an if statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype  guard-for-in`

I have this same logic in other parts of the code but this is the only place where I still have this error after wrapping the for content inside the if with the `hasOwnProperty` method

Comment: I don’t get this warning for this code. No repro.

Comment: Me neither, I can't reproduce it. I decided to just ignore it